# New-AzureADPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewPolicy in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to follow the instructions on the Microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) to configure a custom token expiry policy.

However I am getting an incomprehensible error message. It does not appear to be a temporary error as I have tried it a few times over the last few days.

I have tried running Powershell as both normal and "as administrator", it makes no difference to the outcome.

```
PS C:\Users\sheakbar> New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @(‘{“TokenLifetimePolicy”:{“Version”:1,”MaxInactiveTime”:”14.00:00:00″,”MaxAgeSing
leFactor”:”90.00:00:00″,”MaxAgeMultiFactor”:”90.00:00:00″,”MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor”:”until-revoked”,”MaxAgeSessionMultiFactor”:”unti
l-revoked”}}’) -DisplayName “OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario” -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type “TokenLifetimePolicy”
New-AzureADPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewPolicy
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 4c0f01de-96b4-4483-8a19-43b411149880
  DateTimeStamp: Thu, 07 Jun 2018 04:28:08 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @(‘{“TokenLifetimePolicy”:{“Version”:1, ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADPolicy], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.NewPolicy
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it seems like your account is not a global admin in your tenant and doesn't enough permissions to excute this powershell command.

**Solution:**

Run the Connect command `Connect-AzureAD` to sign in to your **Azure AD admin account**.

Comment: sign in with azure ad admin account , still getting same issue

Comment: Hi @aleemakbarsk ,  Is this admin account a member in this tenant? or a guest user?

Comment: Member in account

Answer (score 0):

If we use [global administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal)(**xxx.onmicrosoft.com**) account to connect-AzureAD.

Then we could New-AzureADPolicy, and I test it on my side with following command

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"MaxInactiveTime":"14.00:00:00","MaxAgeSingleFactor":"90.00:00:00","MaxAgeMultiFactor":"90.00:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"until-revoked","MaxAgeSessionMultiFactor":"until-revoked"}}') -DisplayName "OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

[image]